# Optimise With Query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, optimization

I have a working PostgreSQL query, but it is taking a considerable amount of time to execute. I need help optimising it.

I have:

- Removed inner queries as much as possible.
- Removed the unnecessary data from the query.
- Created a `with` query which gets the required data from the beginning

I need help to optimise this query

```
    with data as (
      select
      e.id,
      e.name,
      t.barcode,
      tt.variant,
      t.cost_cents::decimal / 100 as ticket_cost,
      t.fee_cents::decimal / 100 as booking_fee
    from
      tickets t
      inner join events e on t.event_id = e.id
      inner join ticket_types tt on t.ticket_type_id = tt.id
    where
      t.status = 2
      and e.source in ('source1', 'source2')
    )
    select
      d.name,
      count(distinct d.barcode) as issued,
      (select count(distinct d2.barcode) from data d2 where d2.id = d.id and d2.variant is null) as sold,
      sum(d.ticket_cost) as ticket_revenue,
      sum(d.booking_fee) as booking_fees
    from
      data d
    group by
      id,
      name
```

Comment: Start with running your query with [explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-explain.html) and `explain analyse`.

Answer (score 0):

Better to detect slow parts with using [EXPLAIN](https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgrespro/9.6/using-explain) .
It will show cost of all parts

Comment: Thanks. It sent me down a rabbit hole. How can I speed up a `join` and a `group_by`?

Comment: Check that you have right Indexes. Avoid using distinct in select part.

Answer (score 0):

You can speed up joins by creating proper indexes.

Also, remove the subquery

```
(select count(distinct d2.barcode) from data d2 where d2.id = d.id and d2.variant is null)
```

from the SELECT clause and add a join to d2 table something like this:

```
select
  d.name,
  count(distinct d.barcode) as issued,
  count(distinct d2.barcode) as sold,
  sum(d.ticket_cost) as ticket_revenue,
  sum(d.booking_fee) as booking_fees
from
  data d
  left join data d2 on (d2.id = d.id and d2.variant is null)
group by
  d.id,
  d.name
```